# align wpf tabcontrol strip

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

I'm trying to align a tabcontrol strip on the right.

Just to be clear - I want the tabs on the top (tabstripplacement), but aligned on the right.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Headers for the `TabItem`'s are located in a panel of type `TabPanel`. We can add `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` for it in the Resources of `TabControl`

```
<TabControl ...>
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabPanel">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <!--...-->
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know why, but ItemsPanel replacement doesn’t work. You must replace template for whole TabControl:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TabControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabControl">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsItemsHost="true"/>
                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="SelectedContent"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TabControl.Template>
    <!-- This XAML doesnt work!-->
    <!--<TabControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemsPanel>-->
</TabControl>
```

Comment: TabControl' template has no ItemsPresenter. That's why modifying ItemsPanel doesn't work. Also, this template contains special panel called TabPanel. And if you try to simply change panel to StackPanel, I'm sure you will be surprised with strange tabs behavior. And the reason is default template for TabItem which was designed especially for TabPanel. When the user selects a tab, the template changes Margin. Common panels never take cares about item margins because it's FrameworkElement level, but not the TabPanel. The TabPanel considers margins and that's why tabs are aligned correctly.