# How to have some tabs aligned left and others aligned right? (TabControl in wpf)

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have a tabcontrol and I want to put some tabitem headers aligned to the left, and others aligned to the right. Like in this mock screenshot:

http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/8894/tabcontrol.png

What I've tried already:

- Styles: I can right align the tabitem using this:

[align wpf tabcontrol strip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800455/align-wpf-tabcontrol-strip)

But I haven't been able to find a way to mix left and right aligned tab items.

- Using two TabControls: I can have two overlapping TabControls, one with left aligned tabs, the other with Right aligned tabs. The difficulty is getting them to switch. Click or MouseDown don't fire consistently when the user clicks the tab header (even with Ishitvisible = true). SelectionChanged doesn't work because if the user has previously selected tab 'D' in TabControl 2, then goes to Tab 'A' and back to 'D' - TabControl 2 doesn't know the selection has changed.

At this point I am out of ideas.

Comment: `Click or MouseDown don't fire consistently when the user clicks the tab header` - What happens instead?  `SelectionChanged...` What should happen?  Please give example of behavior that's happening and the target behavior.

Comment: The "header" doesn't fire MouseDown events. You can put a TextBlock as the header content, but then it is smaller than the full header, so sometimes it will capture the click, sometimes it wont.

Comment: SelectionChanged only fires if the user changes tab in that tabcontrol. If you change from one tab control tab back to the first tab control tab, that tabcontrol doesn't register a SelectionChanged event, because for it, the selection hasn't changed. (Does that make sense? If not, its best to make a dummy application and try yourself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try overwriting the Template for the `TabPanel`, however if that doesn't work you'll have to overwrite the `TabControl.Template`. Default control templates can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137.aspx)

**Edit**

Just tested, and `TabPanel` doesn't have a template you can override, so your best bet would be to overwrite the `TabControl.Template` to use your own Panel for hosting TabItems.

Comment: Doesn't he have to handle the layout of the children (TabItems)?  Templates seem to be more for the look, rather than where the children are located. ?

Comment: @jberger `TabItems` are hosted in a `TabPanel`, and I wasn't sure if you could overwrite that to display items differently. I just tested and you can't, so I'm guessing the best option would be to overwrite the `TabControl.Template`

Comment: Got it. The solution is to use the Tab.control template code described in the link, but change the TabPanel (x:Name="HeaderPanel") to a Grid and set the Column definitions (Widths Auto, Auto, Auto, *, Auto). Then you can set the Grid.Column="?" for each of the TabItems.

Comment: After looking here, I replaced the TabPanel with a DockPanel and it works as OP desired without having the limitations of the Grid columns. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thank "Andrew Hanlon", you can use Blend to edit the `TabControl` template.

- Replace `TabPanel` with `DockPanel`
- Then add `HorizontalAlignment="Right"`

It works with me.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up inserting a hidden tab between the tabs on the left and right to separate them.
Simple, and almost does what I want, but the size isn't automatic.

```
<TabItem IsEnabled="False" Visibility="Hidden">
  <TabItem.Header>
      <Label Content=" " Width="200"/>
  </TabItem.Header>
</TabItem>
```