# WPF: How to pin/align tabs to the right, while keeping all others aligned left with TabControl?

Tags: wpf

I am aiming to have a similar tab functionality as in the Visual Studio, where document tabs are aligned left, but some are aligned right, like in this screenshot:
[image]

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493781/how-to-have-some-tabs-aligned-left-and-others-aligned-right-tabcontrol-in-wpf), but it suggested overriding the default `TabControl.Template` or using a `DockPanel` instead of `TabControl`, but I couldn't find any good examples for either of these solutions and I don't even know where to begin. Does anyone have any such examples, or is there a simpler way to achieve this?