# How to right-align last TabControl tab?

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, tabcontrol

Is there a way to make last tab on TabControl right-aligned ?
Want to make the last one separate from the first few.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

This post may be old, but i stumbled across it while searching for an answer to the same question, so i thought I'd share the quick and dirty solution I ended up with.

I just put two TabControls on top of each other in a Grid, and right-aligned the TabPanel on one of them (thanks go out to [Meleak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800455/align-wpf-tabcontrol-strip#answer-4802250)):

```xml
 <Grid>
    <TabControl x:Name="_tabsRight" GotFocus="OnTabFocused" >
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TabPanel">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>

        <TabItem x:Name="JustAHiddenTabItemToDeselectTheRealOne" Visibility="Hidden" />

        <!-- Last tab -->
        <TabItem Header="Last one" >
            <!-- Last content... -->
        </TabItem>

    </TabControl>
    <TabControl x:Name="_tabsLeft" GotFocus="OnTabFocused" >

        <!-- First tab -->
        <TabItem Header="1st" >
            <!-- First content... -->
        </TabItem>

        <!-- Second tab -->
        <TabItem Header="2nd" >
            <!-- Second content... -->
        </TabItem>

    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Then, in the OnTabFocused event handler, we need to bring the bottom-most TabControl to the front when the user clicks a TabItem:

```
private int _zIncrementor = 0;
/// <summary>
/// Hack to make two TabControls act as one.
/// </summary>
private void OnTabFocused(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tab = (TabControl)sender;
    var otherTab = (tab == _tabsLeft) ? _tabsRight : _tabsLeft;

    Grid.SetZIndex(tab, ++_zIncrementor);
    otherTab.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

Comment: I was unable to click on the underlying tab. adding a mousedown event handler via following code fixed it:
        private void _tabs_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Point pt = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);

            var element = this.InputHitTest(pt) as System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TabPanel;

            if (element !=null && _tabsLeft.IsAncestorOf(element))
            {
                _tabsRight.Focus();
                _tabsRight.SelectedIndex=1;
            }

        }

Comment: @Derrick - Thanks! For me, the proposed answer worked fine in debug mode, but when I eventually released the application I found I had to do a similar trick.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.blogs.intuidev.com/post/2010/02/10/TabControlStyling_PartThree.aspx) is an example project on templating the TabControl tabs.  I would probably use a Grid with three columns of width "Auto", * and "Auto" and put a StackPanel in the first column to hold the first set of tabs and then just the last tab by itself in the last column with the middle column being empty and just taking up the remaining space.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have two tabs at left and one at right,  You can have the third invisible tab inbetween and `width` of the invisible tab can be calculated by subtracting the `Width` of all three visible tabs from the `Actualwidth` of the `Window` which gives us the remaining space.

Here is the sample code

```
<TabControl x:Name="_tabsLeft" GotFocus="OnTabFocused" >

    <!-- First tab -->
    <TabItem Header="1st" >
        <!-- First content... -->
    </TabItem>

    <!-- Second tab -->
    <TabItem Header="2nd" >
        <!-- Second content... -->
    </TabItem>

     <!-- Third invisible tab -->
    <TabItem Header="Im not visible in UI" Visibility="Hidden" x:Name="invisibletab" >
        <!-- I'm not visible in UI... -->
    </TabItem>

    <!-- Last tab -->
    <TabItem Header="Last one" >
        <!-- Last content... -->
    </TabItem>

</TabControl>
```

Backend Code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();       
    this.SizeChanged += window_SizeChanged;
}
private void window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    invisibletab.Width = this.ActualWidth - 550; // where the 550 is the sum of the actual width of visible tabs
}
```

Comment: Downvoters. .  Will you pls leave a comment on why this is downvoted.  This is the simplest working solution for the question.